# Identify last called stored procedure name in a parent stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below is the definition of Stored proc ProcA:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ProcA]
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC ProcABC
    INSERT INTO LoggingTable(   Object_Name, LastCallDatetime   )
    SELECT                      'ProcABC',      GETDATE();
END
```

Upon execution of Stored Proc ProcA, when performing the Insert (for logging) I need to identify the last called stored proc name dynamically instead of hardcodeding it as 'ProcABC'

regards

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't any DDL in your question. I'm guessing you forgot to paste it after *"Stored Proc A definition:"*? Please do include it.

Comment: Added now, hope that makes more sense.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. There are no parameters in your SP, so how do you determine which other SP needs to be executed?

Comment: why don't you declare a variable and set it every time you call a stored procedure ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I would still be hardcoding the SP name though, in my actual code I am calling around 40 SPs in a sequence and then carrying out the logging, I was thinking more on the lines of using DMVs to identify every proc call once its called, i'll keep researching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the CONTEXT_INFO session variable to store up to 128 binary bytes.

For example:

```
--Parent Proc
CREATE OR ALTER PROC Parent
AS
DECLARE @CallingProc SYSNAME
SELECT TOP 1 @CallingProc = name FROM sys.procedures WHERE object_id = @@PROCID

DECLARE @BinVar VARBINARY(128)
SET @BinVar = CONVERT(VARBINARY, @CallingProc, 0)

SET CONTEXT_INFO @BinVar

EXEC Child

GO
--Child Proc
CREATE OR ALTER PROC Child 
AS
DECLARE @CallingProc SYSNAME
DECLARE @BinVar VARBINARY(128)

SET @BinVar = CONTEXT_INFO()

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @BinVar, 0)

GO

EXEC Parent -- Will return 'Parent' even though the SELECT occurred in the Child proc
```

This way you can pass the procedure call stack names from parent to child up to the limit of the CONTEXT_INFO variable. To get around the limitation you can use a reference alias table to map short names with the full procedure names.

Hope this helps

Comment: No worries GDS, I was also thinking to build the complete linkage without worrying about aliases you can define an input parameter in each procedure which accepts a GUID with default as NULL. If it's NULL then that stored procedure can generate a GUID and pass that through to it's child procedures.

That way no matter at what point a procedure is called in the hierarchy of calling procedures you'll capture the whole chain for that execution. In each procedure you can insert the GUID, the calling procedure name and the current procedure name into a table.

Comment: @MysticHeroes Modern versions of SQL Server offer [`Session_Context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). It's much more convenient and flexible than `Context_Info`.

Comment: Neat, hadn't seen that before! Has a larger 1 MB limit and accepts more than just binary which is handy.

Answer (score 0):

create one table as below and insert data as parent_proc as "A" and sp_name as "ABC" with list of input parameter as "in_param"(@1, @2, @3...)

```
CREATE Table sp_list(parent_proc, sp_name, in_param)
```

Now make dynamic SQL to perform the task,